# Telegrambot погода pyowm по кнопке

Tags: python, telebot, pyowm

Как в TelegramBot вывести погоду pyowm, чтобы после нажатия на одну из 3 кнопок был запрос города и далее выводились метеоданные. Но чтобы при этом работали и остальные кнопки! Ошибка: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'answer' referenced before assignment

Кусок кода на Python:

elif message.text == '☁⛅ Погода':

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '☑️Введіть місто для пошуку: ')
try:
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
    oblaka = w.clouds
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    vlazhnost = w.humidity

    answer = "В місті " + message.text + " зараз " + w.detailed_status + "!" + "\n"
    answer += "Температура зараз приблизно " + str(temp) + " ℃." + "\n\n"

    if temp < 10:
        answer += ("Зараз ппц як холодно, вдягайся як танк!")
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += ("Зараз прохолодно, вдягайся потепліше.")
    else:
        answer += ("Не холодно, йди хоч в трусах :)")

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
except:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

```
except:
    answer = 'что-то ты сделал не так, а лучше оборачивай в функцию'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
```

просто `answer` не инициализирован ни в блоке `except:` ни до начала `try:`

Comment: Можешь скинуть пример?

Comment: пример чего? как происходит инициализация переменных в Python? Как работает try/except? pep8 могу предложить почитать, книгу какую-нибудь по Python.